Why is a circuit drawing power with no devices plugged in?
I have an old house with glass screw-in fuses, 100 amp. Wiring is copper about 1945 in Ontario, Canada. Many prior renovations have the kitchen outlets, basement lights & outlets, sunporch outlets and run under the driveway to garage outlets.
One day the compressor on the fridge blew (one of these outlets). I find out on my hydro bill that it's $350 instead of the usual $70. We unplugged the fuse that had the fridge on it and the power draw stopped.
So when the fuse is screwed in and nothing is plugged into the sockets and no lights are on, this fuse draws 50X the normal power. I can go online and see the daily usage. When the fuse is unscrewed, it's fine, no power on this line. My question is what could be causing the high demand in power if nothing is plugged in when fuse is in? Would it be the panel or something on one of the many lines?

Maybe a partial short.  Enough to use electricity, but not good enough to blow the fuse.  It might be faster to replace that whole line, than trying to find the problem, unless it is right at the receptacle or the panel.  Insulation on 1945 wires might not be good now.

Where did you get 50X? Did you mean 5 (350/7)? (And fuses don't draw power--they merely pass current.)

Is there only one outlet on that circuit?

Hot water heater?
